# Why do I loose parts of the plot when exporting it as metafile?

Tags: r, plot, export

I'm working with GLMs and therefore do some plots with the "visreg" package, and I also add usual plots to them. My script looks like this:

```
library(visreg)
visreg(model01, scale = "response", type="conditional",line=list(col="green"), ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,400), rug=F, axes=F, ann=F)
par(new=T)
plot(data$x ~ data$y, ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,400), col=rgb(0,100,50,50, maxColorValue=255), pch=19, cex=2, axes=F, ann=F)
par(new=T)
visreg(model02, scale = "response", type="conditional",line=list(col="red"), ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,400), rug=F, axes=F, ann=F )
par(new=T)
plot(data$x ~ data$z, ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,400), col=rgb(0,50,100,50, maxColorValue=255), pch=19, cex=2, las=1, xlab="label01", ylab="label02")
axis(1)
axis(2, las=1)
box()
col1 <- c(rgb(0,100,50, maxColorValue=155), rgb(0,50,100, maxColorValue=155))
legend (315, 1.05, legend=c("bla01", "bla02"), col=c("green","red"), y.intersp=1.3, cex=0.9, lty=1, lwd=2, bty="n")
legend (309, 1.06, legend=c("",""), col=col1, pch=19, y.intersp=1.2, bty="n")
```

The `visreg()` parts plot the regression model while the `plot()` parts plot the corresponding data. The whole plot looks the way I want it in RStudio, but when I export it as a metafile I loose the `plot()` parts of it (except the axis labels, they are still there). Does anybody know why that is and what I can do to export it all as a metafile?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: I don't know, but I categorically avoid metafiles for this reason. Depending on the need, I export as PNG or PDF (very rarely as SVG). Getting graphs to show well in MS-based documents is a pain, typically forcing me to up the resolution (`png("file.png", res=300)` so that it looks decent on-screen; the default of 72dpi is fine for basic stuff but not-so-much for higher-quality presentations/reports.

Comment: Yeah I also found the 72dpi to be to low. I took the detour of saving it as PDF and opening it in the Adobe Illustrator, where I can export it as EMF.
Thanks!